# Only last added notification gets triggered

Tags: ios, swift, usernotifications

I'm updating notification to the **UNUserNotification** framework for my alarm-like app, and I thought I succeeded, but I realized that when I set more than one alarm I only get notified the latest one. Repeating days are working the dough.
Could it be a problem of trigger identifier that is getting the same string as previous ones and overwrites it?
I really don't understand this behavior and I can't find where's the problem.

**This is the code:**

```
func setRouteNotification(_ date: Date, onWeekdaysForNotify weekdays:[Int], snoozeEnabled:Bool,  onSnooze: Bool, soundName: String, routeName: String, index: Int) {
    configureCategory()
    // Notification content
    let routeCheckNotificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    let datesForNotification = correctDate(date, onWeekdaysForNotify: weekdays)
    routeCheckNotificationContent.title = "Hello!! Are you ready to cycle?"
    routeCheckNotificationContent.body = "Check route for alerts?"
    routeCheckNotificationContent.categoryIdentifier = Id.notificationCategory
    routeCheckNotificationContent.sound = UNNotificationSound.init(named: soundName + ".mp3")

    let repeating: Bool = !weekdays.isEmpty
    routeCheckNotificationContent.userInfo = ["snooze" : snoozeEnabled, "index": index, "soundName": soundName, "routeName": routeName, "repeating" : repeating]
    //repeat weekly if repeat weekdays are selected
    //no repeat with snooze notification
    if !weekdays.isEmpty && !onSnooze{ }

    syncAlarmModel()
    var counter = 1

    for d in datesForNotification {
        if onSnooze {
            alarmModel.alarms[index].date = Scheduler.correctSecondComponent(date: alarmModel.alarms[index].date)
        } else {
            alarmModel.alarms[index].date = d
        }

        // Notification trigger
        let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        let components = calendar.dateComponents(in: .current, from: d)
        let newComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, timeZone: .current, month: components.month, day: components.day, hour: components.hour, minute: components.minute, second: components.second)
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: newComponents, repeats: true)

        // Notification Request
        let routeNotificationRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "routeNotificationRequest\(scheduledNotifications.count + counter)", content: routeCheckNotificationContent, trigger: trigger)

        // Add request
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(routeNotificationRequest) { (Error) in
            if Error != nil {
                print("something went wrong with adding notification")
            }
        }
        print("added request\(alarmModel.alarms.count + weekdays.count + counter)")
        scheduledNotifications.append(counter)
        print("scheduled notifications are \(scheduledNotifications.count)")
        counter = ( counter + 1 )
    }
    print(alarmModel.alarms)
}
```

Any idea of why is not setting all the programmed notifications?
Thank you very much as usual.

EDIT:

I tried setting up an array `var scheduledNotifications: [Int] = []` that stores a progressive number as notifications gets added, and use that as the identifier for the request

```
let routeNotificationRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "routeNotificationRequest\(scheduledNotifications.count + counter)", content: routeCheckNotificationContent, trigger: trigger)
```

so I'm sure that all added notifications have a unique request identifier, but nothing changed, still gets notified only the latest one.

EDIT 2:
console output when I set 2 notification for everyday:

```
added request9B642AB7-D4F3-4BDA-A5B3-D259419390D5
scheduled notifications are 1
added requestBA0EF286-CD4D-408D-AEFC-E3DED24FBBB4
scheduled notifications are 2
added request947FEFEF-0B4E-4163-8435-DCEC725F21F7
scheduled notifications are 3
added request8FF19184-F970-45AD-95FE-39CFABF83348
scheduled notifications are 4
added requestA447CABF-AD80-4A73-B214-B8A1AA47F76B
scheduled notifications are 5
added request217EF2E4-6241-4840-9431-16744F2E5314
scheduled notifications are 6
added request28C92EF2-143C-4364-9CC3-EB5335AA9B6F
scheduled notifications are 7
[fix_it_mapView.Alarm(date: 2018-10-06 13:28:00 +0000, enabled: true, snoozeEnabled: false, repeatWeekdays: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], uuid: "1C5A746F-F97D-4149-A0CC-47E6334BF3C3", mediaID: "", mediaLabel: "Burlone", label: "Route", onSnooze: false, routeLabel: "prova3"), fix_it_mapView.Alarm(date: 2018-09-23 13:29:00 +0000, enabled: true, snoozeEnabled: false, repeatWeekdays: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], uuid: "B708BC27-82AA-4AA2-A8CA-252460E48476", mediaID: "", mediaLabel: "Burlone", label: "Route", onSnooze: false, routeLabel: "prova1")]
dates for notification are: [2018-09-30 13:28:00 +0000, 2018-10-01 13:28:00 +0000, 2018-10-02 13:28:00 +0000, 2018-10-03 13:28:00 +0000, 2018-10-04 13:28:00 +0000, 2018-10-05 13:28:00 +0000, 2018-10-06 13:28:00 +0000]
added request2467230C-BC4A-4307-A0FA-108C5C291DCC
scheduled notifications are 8
added requestF27D9E76-BCCC-4E3A-91D7-CA60E64B61B9
scheduled notifications are 9
added requestDFF37582-AB57-4029-A480-6FFA4068E316
scheduled notifications are 10
added requestBC5633BD-234C-4555-8259-988908B6E4DA
scheduled notifications are 11
added requestEC35384F-2E7F-4267-A745-777E0C2A2CE8
scheduled notifications are 12
added requestFF866674-ED94-4BA0-8BA5-E8314521EA4F
scheduled notifications are 13
added request4D739860-83CB-43F9-895D-2E8D48C5154E
scheduled notifications are 14
[fix_it_mapView.Alarm(date: 2018-10-06 13:28:00 +0000, enabled: true, snoozeEnabled: false, repeatWeekdays: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], uuid: "1C5A746F-F97D-4149-A0CC-47E6334BF3C3", mediaID: "", mediaLabel: "Burlone", label: "Route", onSnooze: false, routeLabel: "prova3"), fix_it_mapView.Alarm(date: 2018-10-06 13:29:00 +0000, enabled: true, snoozeEnabled: false, repeatWeekdays: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], uuid: "B708BC27-82AA-4AA2-A8CA-252460E48476", mediaID: "", mediaLabel: "Burlone", label: "Route", onSnooze: false, routeLabel: "prova1")]
dates for notification are: [2018-09-23 13:29:00 +0000, 2018-10-01 13:29:00 +0000, 2018-10-02 13:29:00 +0000, 2018-10-03 13:29:00 +0000, 2018-10-04 13:29:00 +0000, 2018-10-05 13:29:00 +0000, 2018-10-06 13:29:00 +0000]
2018-09-23 15:27:12.771112+0200 fix-it mapView[14162:297740] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
2018-09-23 15:27:12.771425+0200 fix-it mapView[14162:297740] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
```

Comment: Please do _not_ add code, error messages, etc as images - they're not searchable, and can't be copied when writing an answer. Also, please [edit] your question and remove commented out code.

Comment: @Ashley Mills. Sorry for the typos and for the image. I edited the question as suggested. Thank you for point that out.

Comment: Do you remove the app everytime you run it to schedule the notifications? if not the new notifications will have same identifiers of a previous run. its better to generate a unique id rather than using a counter.

Comment: @hasan. no I don't remove the app, I though that new notifications would overwrite old runs with new settings if using the same identifier, what would be you approach for a unique identifier other than the counter I use?

Comment: Would this be what you ment? `let uuid = UUID().uuidString`

Comment: @vincenzo I am not sure. but this is a safer approach. try it plz.

Comment: Where do you get `datesForNotification` from and how large is that array? What's the order of dates?

Comment: @Yury Imashev. `datesForNotification` it's a Date array that get populated as the return from the correctDate method that is called inside the `setRouteNotification`method `let datesForNotification = correctDate(date, onWeekdaysForNotify: weekdays)`. weekdays is an Int array that gets populated from week days for repetition tableview selection

Comment: So if I got you right, you have one notification per weekday? How do you check that the only last notification fires?

Comment: I set 2 notification for the seven days 1 minute apart from each other and only the second fires. running it on iPhone it fires everyday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying different things I think I solved it, but I don't understand why it doesn't work the way I was doing things. `d` is the Date value taken from the for in loop in the `setRouteNotification`function that represent the weekday for the notification to be scheduled ( see the code in the question )
Working:

```
let components2 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday,.hour,.minute,.second,], from: d)
let trigger2 = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components2, repeats: true)
```

Not working:

```
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let components = calendar.dateComponents(in: .current, from: d)
var newComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, timeZone: .current, month: components.month, day: components.day, hour: components.hour, minute: components.minute, second: components.second, weekday: components.weekday)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: NewComponents, repeats: true)
```

Comment: Can you make your answer readable and generic. What is `d` here?

Comment: @Honey. What you mean generic? Hope I edited my answer the way you ment. Let me know if not.Thank you

Comment: @hasan. Thank for pointing out that something was wrong with my date, and for the effort you put in helping me.

Answer (score 1):

I used the current date in seconds as the identifier and it worked fine with me as follow:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: []) { (granted, error) in


        if granted {

            let routeCheckNotificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            routeCheckNotificationContent.title = "Hello!! Are you ready to cycle?"
            routeCheckNotificationContent.body = "Check route for alerts?"
            routeCheckNotificationContent.categoryIdentifier = "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)"
            routeCheckNotificationContent.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

            routeCheckNotificationContent.userInfo = ["snooze" : false, "index": 1, "soundName": "1", "routeName": "hmm", "repeating" : true]


            self.addNotification(content: routeCheckNotificationContent, date: Date().addingTimeInterval(30))
            self.addNotification(content: routeCheckNotificationContent, date: Date().addingTimeInterval(60))

        } else {

            print("Notification permission dendied !!")
        }
    }
}

func addNotification(content: UNMutableNotificationContent, date: Date) {

    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

    let components = calendar.dateComponents(in: .current, from: date)
    let newComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, timeZone: .current, month: components.month, day: components.day, hour: components.hour, minute: components.minute, second: components.second)

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: newComponents, repeats: true)
    // Notification Request
    let routeNotificationRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "\(date.timeIntervalSince1970)", content: content, trigger: trigger)


    // Add request
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(routeNotificationRequest) { (Error) in
        if Error != nil {
            print("something went wrong with adding notification")
        }
    }
}
```

**Maybe, there is something wrong with your dates!**

Comment: Changed for the UUID but result is the same, only second scheduled notification gets triggered.

Comment: no, I set it like this: `let uuid = UUID().uuidString
                let routeNotificationRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuid, content: routeCheckNotificationContent, trigger: trigger)`

Comment: @hasan. `routeCheckNotificationContent.identifier = UUID().uuidString`throws me an error: `Value of type 'UNMutableNotificationContent' has no member 'identifier'`. Isn't the request needed to be with different identifiers?

Comment: give me a few minutes I will try it for you

Comment: @vincenzo I added the example that worked for me. both notifications get triggered.

Comment: well yes it has to do with dates, but I cannot find were is the error.. is there a way to share the project ?

Comment: when I set the 2 notifications I get the output from console ad the EDIT 2 in question.

Comment: my project does not contain any code at all rather than those you see.

Comment: I ment to share mine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180616/discussion-between-hasan-and-vincenzo).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and realized that it's happening because I was using the same identifier @"ID" for multiple notifications. When I made the identifiers unique, they were all triggered.

```
UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"ID" content:notification trigger:trigger];
```